# finding a pattern of letters in a word

Tags: c, fopen, c99, printf, strstr

Is there any way that I can search for "tro_ _ _e" where the underscores represent missing letters?

I have a text file with a 7 letter word on each line. e.g

```
trouble
control
reached
further
helping
shatter
biggest
```

I am trying to compare each word to the string

```
char check[10]="tro\0\0\0e"
```

at the moment I am reading each line and comparing using:

```
if(strstr(pword,check)!=NULL)
{
    fprintf(wfile,"%s\n",pword);
    }
}

fclose(file);

fclose(wfile);
```

I realise that my current output in wfile:

```
control
trouble
```

is due to the fact that there are three \0s in between the "tro" and the "e" and so the comparison is just finding "tro" in the words.

Is there any way that I can search for "tro_ _ _e" where the underscores represent missing letters?

This is for a hangman game and so the words in the file are not always the same, not always 7 letters long  and the pattern is not always "tro_ _ _e" as the pattern represents the letters already guessed by a player. The answer in this case: "trouble"

For example, if a player guessed "r", "u" and "l". I would have a string which was literally.

`char check[10]="\0r\0u\0l\0\0\0\0\0"` so the search I would want would be for any words with a pattern "_r_u_l"

Comment: Odd, I seem to be missing the "retag" link on this message. Also, since the message amounts to "is there a regexp library for C", the answers so far disappoint me.

Comment: i did not intend c# tag, was going for c99

Comment: The question has been updated to clarify my problem

Comment: No, not in a straight forwarded manner. Logical implementation can achieve. I assume the string length is constant as per your example.You may have to search for the strings separately "tro" and "e" at their expected string positions.

Comment: char check[10] is always 10 characters long but the problem word ("trouble" in this case, can be from 3-9 chars in length

Answer (score 1):

If you are truly open to a C# solution, as suggested by your tags:

```
string pword = "control\r\ntrouble\r\nreached\r\nfurther\r\nhelping\r\nshatter\r\nbiggest";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("tro...e");
System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(pword);
foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in mc)
{
   Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: incorrect tag of c#, i was going for c99. Also, have updated question with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your problem actually is but I guess you could combine two searches/conditions with AND, like: 
`if(strstr(pword,check) != NULL && pword[6]=='e') ...`

Comment: You need to check if it's valid to access `pword[6]`. Also it's wrong: you have no guarantee `strstr` finds the `check` at the beginning of `pword`.

Comment: I have updated the question to show you the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess with `\0` - Every function in `string.h` think that it ends strings. Use `_`.

Probably you should write your own function. something like:

```
int isval(const char *word,const char *pat) {
 while (*word) {
  if (*pat!='_' && *pat!=*word) return 0;
  word++;
  pat++;
 }
 return !*pat;
}
```

Comment: the only reason I have NULL spaces in the string is because as each letter is guessed, it runs through a check to see if it is part of the word and, if it is, that letter is copied across to a blank string (check[50])

Comment: for(i==0;i<=(strlen(word));i++){if (letter guessed == word[i]){check[i]=word[i];}}

Comment: Then init that blank string to something else, or be care that this is not C string, and you cannot use string functions on that. (blank string and empty string are not the same)

Answer (score 0):

Posix systems have <regex.h>, with regcomp, regexec and so forth, if you need an extensible solution.